# Error while trying to delete a session in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, session, ruby-on-rails-4, session-cookies

New to Rails. I have a model named Admin in my rails application. when i tried to delete the session i am getting No route Match Error.
I have created session controller to manage sessions shown below

```
class AdminSessionsController < ApplicationController

  before_action :confirm_logged_in, :except => [:new, :create, :destroy]

  def destroy
    session[:admin_id] = nil
    flash[:notice] = "You are now logged out"
    render("new")
  end

end
```

Routes I defined in routes.rb

```
resources :admin_sessions, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
```

I have link in some other view to delete a session

```
<%= link_to "Sign out", :controller => "admin_sessions", :action => "destroy" %>
```

And I am getting the following Error

```
No route matches {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"admin_sessions"}
```

Please help somebody!

Comment: Did you restart the server after you updated everything?

Comment: @Casper Yes. I did but the result is same

Answer (score 0):

You define resources while it's resource. You do not depend on specific id, so it always should respond with one resource (DELETE /admin_sessions/id vs DELETE /admin_sessions). Change in your route resources to resource and it will work.

Comment: When i changed it from resources to resource as @konole told i am getting a new error as follows **undefined local variable or method `new_admin_session_path'** for a line in the view <%= link_to "Sign in", new_admin_session_path %>

Comment: Type in "rake routes" in terminal and check what is proper variable for helper (ofc add _path to the end)